# MediaWiki API Incorrect User Rights

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

I'm battling with the WikiEditor extension of MediaWiki 1.27. When a user tries to use the fancy image upload button from the enhanced editor toolbar, I get the message "You must be logged in to upload files."

So far I've narrowed it down to the user rights returned from the API being incomplete. I've tested with the following two API calls:

The one WikiEditor uses: `action=query&meta=userinfo&uiprop=rights`
returns:

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "userinfo": {
            "id": 1006,
            "name": "john_smith",
            "rights": [
                "read",
                "createpage",
                "createtalk",
                "writeapi",
                "editmyusercss",
                "editmyuserjs",
                "viewmywatchlist",
                "editmywatchlist",
                "viewmyprivateinfo",
                "editmyprivateinfo",
                "editmyoptions",
                "autocreateaccount"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

However, this API call: `action=query&list=users&ususers=john_smith&usprop=rights` returns:

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "users": [
            {
                "userid": 1006,
                "name": "john_smith",
                "rights": [
                    "block",
                    "createaccount",
                    "delete",
                    "bigdelete",
                    "deletedhistory",
                    "deletedtext",
                    "undelete",
                    "editinterface",
                    "editusercss",
                    "edituserjs",
                    "editcontentmodel",
                    "import",
                    "importupload",
                    "move",
                    "move-subpages",
                    "move-rootuserpages",
                    "move-categorypages",
                    "patrol",
                    "autopatrol",
                    "protect",
                    "editprotected",
                    "rollback",
                    "upload",
                    "reupload",
                    "reupload-shared",
                    "unwatchedpages",
                    "autoconfirmed",
                    "editsemiprotected",
                    "ipblock-exempt",
                    "blockemail",
                    "markbotedits",
                    "apihighlimits",
                    "browsearchive",
                    "noratelimit",
                    "movefile",
                    "unblockself",
                    "suppressredirect",
                    "mergehistory",
                    "managechangetags",
                    "deleterevision",
                    "read",
                    "createpage",
                    "createtalk",
                    "writeapi",
                    "editmyusercss",
                    "editmyuserjs",
                    "viewmywatchlist",
                    "editmywatchlist",
                    "viewmyprivateinfo",
                    "editmyprivateinfo",
                    "editmyoptions",
                    "autocreateaccount",
                    "edit",
                    "minoredit",
                    "purge",
                    "sendemail",
                    "applychangetags",
                    "changetags"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm totally stumped and at a loss of why these two very similar API calls return a different set of rights. As a result, users are not able to upload images via the enhanced editor button.

Comment: Are you using a [bot password](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Bot_passwords)? Or an expiring user group (I think that's an 1.28 feature but might be wrong)?

Comment: @Tgr No, not using bot password or expiring user group. Why would bot password have an effect?

Comment: Bot passwords allow limiting the permissions the user has when logging in via that password.